# Issue with concatenation with delimiter formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to concatenate cells in every other column with a semi-colon delimiter.  The formula that I have, and is essentially working is:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(H2&" "&J2&" "&L2&" "&N2&" "&P2&" "&R2&" "&T2&" "&V2&" "&X2&" "&Z2)," ","; ")="","",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(H2&" "&J2&" "&L2&" "&N2&" "&P2&" "&R2&" "&T2&" "&V2&" "&X2&" "&Z2)," ","; "))
```

But the problem that I am having with this is that some of the cells contain text with spaces, and the formula is putting the delimiter in place of the legitimate spaces.  How do I correct this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

`=IF(COUNTA(H2,J2,L2,N2,P2,R2,T2,V2,X2,Z2),H2&";"&J2&";"&L2&";"&N2&";"&P2&";"&R2&";"&T2&";"&V2&";"&X2&";"&Z2,"")`

or to only show delimiters once when you have blanks perhaps try this version

`=SUBSTITUTE(IF(H2="","",";"&H2)&IF(J2="","",";"&J2)&IF(L2="","",";"&L2)&IF(N2="","",";"&N2)&IF(P2="","",";"&P2)&IF(R2="","",";"&R2)&IF(T2="","",";"&T2)&IF(V2="","",";"&V2)&IF(X2="","",";"&X2)&IF(Z2="","",";"&Z2),";","",1)`

Comment: That left extra delimiters in there even though the cell was blank.

Comment: OK, I'm a bit confused, doesn't the accepted solution also do that? I assumed that either all cells were populated or none, isn't that the case? I amended my answer to show a version which will get rid of additional delimiters if some cells are populated but not others

Comment: Yes, it does do that.  I accepted it based on the calling out of the temporary delimiter.  I changed my code to find and replace all spaces with a pipe, then run the original formula, and then run another find and replace of the pipe with the space.  Your second formula is the one that I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `SUBSTITUTE` on space characters that are not only your temporary delimiter but also a pattern in your concatenated strings.

The dirty yet quick solution is to use a temporary delimiter pattern that won't appear in your `H2, L2, N2...` cells. Here I picked up `###` but any other pattern would do the trick.

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(H2&"###"&J2&"###"&L2&"###"&N2&"###"&P2&"###"&R2&"###"&T2&"###"&V2&"###"&X2&"###"&Z2),"###","; ")="","",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(H2&"###"&J2&"###"&L2&"###"&N2&"###"&P2&"###"&R2&"###"&T2&"###"&V2&"###"&X2&"###"&Z2),"###","; "))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I did.  I used a pipe delimiter for the legitimate spaces and then ran the formula.